# Prove the geometric interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

Let $\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4$ be non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ such that the solution set of the system $\begin{bmatrix} \vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \vec v_3 & \vec v_4 \space | \space \vec 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a hyperplane.  What is the geometric interpretation of $Span \left \{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4\right \}$

Going through an example, it tells me that the geometric interpretation is a line through the origin, but I'm not sure how to prove this more rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

By definition, a hyperplane is of dimension $n-1$, hence the solution space has dimension $3$.

By rank-nullity theorem, can you conclude about the rank of the column space?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't learned about the rank-nullity theorem and column spaces haven't been taught yet (so it's undefined as of right now).  I have really only learned about vectors in euclidean space (subspaces, dot product, cross product, projections etc..) and systems of linear equations (homogeneous systems, matrices, RREF etc...).  What I can deduce with the knowledge I have is that the rank of the corresponding matrix of the system is 1, and that there are 3 free variables.  I don't know how I can use this to prove the geometric interpretation

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the vectors must be non-zero, becaue otherwise you would have more than a hyperplane of solutions. Let $\vec v_1\neq\vec 0$.

The hyperplane of solutions paired with $\vec v_1\neq \vec 0$ means that for any three coefficients $b, c, d\in \Bbb R$, there is an $a\in \Bbb R$ such that
$$
a\cdot\vec v_1+b\cdot\vec v_2+c\cdot\vec v_3+d\cdot\vec v_4  = \vec 0
$$
Or, said differently:
$$
a\cdot\vec v_1= -b\cdot\vec v_2-c\cdot\vec v_3-d\cdot\vec v_4
$$
In other words, $\operatorname{Span}(\vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4)\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(\vec v_1)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the part where you say the hyperplane of solutions paired with... Why does it tell us that the linear combination of the vectors is the zero vector